# como transformar una matriz de estructura a una matriz de lista en prolog

Tags: prolog

Tengo esta entrada en Prolog y le pregunto por la  función x

```
X((1,0,1,0),(1,0,1,0))
```

y quiero obtener de salida

```
[[1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0]]
```

¿cómo podría hacer?

se que la función `univ` me lo convierte a lista y viceversa pero si yo coloco `X((1,0,1,0)) =.. Lista` me devuelve `[X,(1,0,1,0)]` y no me sirve

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes crear un predicado que convierta una fila en una lista. Para ello, con `=../2` puedes ir cogiendo un elemento de la tupla y tratar recursivamente la cola:

```
row_to_list(X, [X]) :- number(X).
row_to_list(X, [H|S]) :- X =.. [_,H|[T]], row_to_list(T,S).
```

Ahora se debe tratar la lista de filas, aplicando el predicado anterior a cada fila:

```
rows_to_list([],[]).
rows_to_list([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :- row_to_list(X,Y), rows_to_list(Xs,Ys).
```

Finalmente, el predicado principal debe transformar la estructura `x((...),(...),...)` es una lista y transformar las filas mediante el predicado anterior:

```
matrix_to_list(X,S) :- X =.. [_|T], rows_to_list(T,S).
```

Por ejemplo:

```
?- matrix_to_list(x((1,0,1,0),(1,0,1,0)),X).
X = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]] ;
false.
```

Si utilizas un intérprete como SWI-Prolog, podrías utilizar el predicado `maplist/3` y ahorrarte la definición de `rows_to_list/2`:

```
matrix_to_list(X,S) :- X =.. [_|T], maplist(row_to_list,T,S).
```